# How can I access "legacy" indicators in Elementary?

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

First time elementary OS user, long time Ubuntu (Gnome) user.

Installed Freya today and I have a couple of issues with indicators.  First, Dropbox indicator isn't showing (found a [post](http://www.elementarynow.com/quick-tip-restoring-dropbox-indicator/) that should fix that, waiting for long-running git checkout so I an log out and test it).

I have an indicator that was written by my employer that shows me my security status and allows me to view a report.  It works in ubuntu (and Gnome-Shell, via the notification tray) but can't find it in Elementary.

I also have Symantec Antivirus installed and its indicator shows up in the dock as a running application, which is annoying.

How can these issues be fixed?  In Gnome-Shell there's an extension that adds what they call "legacy" indicator to the Gnome-Shell indicators.  Is there something similar in Elementary OS?

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Incompatibility between third-party apps and Wingpanel is something that elementary can do little about, as it is third-party devs' job to provide this kind of support. In fact, there has been a lot of talk about moving away from Ayatana indicators for future releases. (see [this blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+spec/new-indicator-framework) for example).

As for the Dropbox indicator, several workarounds have been provided. Search the questions here on StackExchange. What worked for me is [this script](https://github.com/nathandyer/elementary-dropbox-mods).

Comment: In gnome-shell there is a plugin that will show legacy appindicators in the gnome-shell indicator framework.  That's what I was looking for.  If nothing like this exists, I'll edit this answer to reflect that it is not possible to "Generally" fix this and mark as correct (Not possible -- Original question was not about specific indicators, but about the existence of a general framework for mapping legacy->elementary indicators.)